# How to set the filter of a pivot table with a date in a userform VBA Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I want to set a filter of a pivot table with the date of a userform. 
The date in the userform is `strDateSelected = dtpDate.Value`.

My code doesn't work and I don't know why. Does anyone see the problem?

```
Private Sub dtpDate_Change()
  Call ExecuteRefresh
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteRefresh()
  Dim pvt As PivotTable
  Dim pf As PivotField
  Dim strDateSelected As String
  Dim strCurrentFV As String

  Set pvt = Worksheets("Sommaire 1").PivotTables("pvtFonctionJournee")
  Set pf = pvt.PivotFields("Date")

  strDateSelected = dtpDate.Value
  Set pf = pvt.PivotFields("Date")
  Call GetFirstPivotFieldValueSelected(pf, strCurrentFV)
  pf.ClearAllFilters
  pf.PivotItems(strCurrentFV).Visible = False
  strDateSelected = Format(strDateSelected, "m\/d\/yyyy")
  pf.PivotItems(strDateSelected).Visible = True
  pvt.RefreshTable
End Sub

Private Sub GetFirstPivotFieldValueSelected(pf As PivotField,   strFirstPFValueSelected As String)
  strFirstPFValueSelected = ""
  For Each Pi In pf.PivotItems
    If Pi.Visible = True Then
        strFirstPFValueSelected = Pi.Value
        Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, on what line?

Comment: If the date exist it work 1/2 times. So this is weird. There is an error when the date does'nt exist.

Comment: pf.PivotItems(strDateSelected).Visible = True

Answer (score 0):

It works with this simple code:

```
 Sub FilterDate()

 For Each pt In Worksheets("Sommaire 1").PivotTables
     With pt.PivotFields("Date")
         .ClearAllFilters
         .CurrentPage = dtpDate.Value
     End With
 Next pt

End Sub
```